# Shortcut - shift right on the apple wireless keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I would like to know how can I use the "Shift right" shortcut ( cmd + ] ) on the apple wireless keyboard.

Here is an image of the keyboard

**Update 1 - french keyboard:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [bachibouzouks.com](https://ilovemymac.bachibouzouks.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/HT1171_01-wireless_keyboard-001-fr.png))</sub>

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That <strike>is</strike> was a picture of the [Apple Wireless Keyboard - Swiss](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184SM/B/apple-wireless-keyboard-swiss?fnode=3e).  Normally you would use the “Swiss French” keyboard layout with that keyboard.

I don't have an Apple Wireless Keyboard - Swiss; I have an Apple Wireless Keyboard - US English.  But I set my keyboard layout to Swiss French (System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources > <kbd>+</kbd> > French > Swiss French) and played around.  Here's what worked for me:

In the Swiss French keyboard layout, you can type a right square bracket using <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>.  So to type the shortcut for “Shift right”, you press (and hold) <kbd>⌘</kbd>, press (and hold) <kbd>⌥</kbd>, press <kbd>6</kbd>, and finally release all keys.

[image: shift right shortcut - swiss french]

#### UPDATE

Your new picture is of an [Apple Wireless Keyboard - French](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184F/B/apple-wireless-keyboard-french).
In the French keyboard layout, you can type a right square bracket using <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>.  So to type the shortcut for “Shift right”, you press and hold <kbd>⌥</kbd>, <kbd>⇧</kbd>, and <kbd>⌘</kbd> simultaneously, and while holding them, press <kbd>)</kbd>.

[image: enter image description here - french]

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer and time. Otherwise (my bad), I'm using a french keyboard, I just update the image, can you help me again on this one? or lead me to the answer, thanks again

Comment: The more important question is, what keyboard layout are you using?  Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources.  What keyboard layouts are listed on the left?

Comment: I'm using a French layout keyboard

Comment: I'm using BBedit, a sofware development. This shortcode is already uses to switch from the current document, however, the shortcode is working on other softwares. Thanks